# AJAX запрос в django

Tags: python, ajax, django

Можете помочь как правильно послать запрос через ajax в django вот собственно код ajax

```
    function ff() {
function load()
{
    $.get('','').done( function (data) {
        data.html('chartContainer1')
    } )
}
    load();
    setInterval(load,5000);}
```

вот сам django

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT volt FROM Robot')
mas_volt = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute('SELECT amper FROM Robot')
mas_amper = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute('SELECT time FROM Robot')
mas_time = cur.fetchall()
l = []

for time in mas_time:
    for ti in time:
        t = int(ti)/1000
        l.append( '{ x:'+str(t) )
i=0
for amper in mas_amper:
    for amp in amper:
        l[i] += ',y:' + str(amp) + '},'
        i+=1
conn.close()
global mylistwr
mylistwr.mylist=l
return render_to_response('index.html',{'list':l,'mass':mas_volt})
```

то есть у меня ajax каждые 5 сек запрашивает бд есть ли новые записи смотрел (статут 200 ок) запрос доходит но в html не добавляется

у меня есть в html div там отрисовывается график

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все сам разобрался вот как сделал

```
function ff() {
function load()
{
    $.get('','').done( function (data) {
        $('#chartContainer1').html(data)
    } )
}
    load();
    setInterval(load,5000);
```